# rule for userid to write his posts

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a firebase json like this:

posts:

```
-Hhnfdb743HvGdF (the post key)
 |
 --- user: josh
 |
 --- profile: /img/img.jpg
 |
 --- userid: v5s8fd8f7 (the auth user id from firebase auth)
```

I'd like to allow only this userid to write his data, so I try:

```
 "posts": {
    "$uid": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": "auth != null && 
               auth.uid == data.child('userid').val()"
    }
 }
```

The problem is it always deny, even if the userid is the same as auth. any ideas why?

```
/posts/-Hhnfdb743HvGdF/userid/v5s8fd8f7
```

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You're using `data` to look up the UID, which is the data as is exists **before** this operation. To get the data as it exists **after** this operation (if the operation is allowed), use `newData`:

```
auth.uid == newData.child('userid').val()"
```

See the Firebase documentation on [existing data vs new data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#existing_data_vs_new_data).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I change data to newData but still deny... any more ideas? :/

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the [minimal, complete/standalone code that writes and gets rejected](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Make sure to hard-code as much as possible, and log values that you can't hard-code such as the UID of the active user.